# Output xml feed data into view

Tags: views

I have an xml feed and i want to display it with a view. 
I have created a content type with the fields that are in the feed but how can i tell the view to get the data from this feed. I don't want to insert my feed data into the database. How can this be done programmatically? Maybe from the theme section in views? Maybe with some hooks like hook_views_data_alter?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you sing drupal 6 or 7 ? and also can you tell me for what purpose you are going to use this feed, for eg property feed

Comment: I'm using drupal 7. And yes, it's a property feed.

Comment: Can you post it as answer with steps, so that it will help the future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

So i solved it. In **hook_views_pre_render** i added something like:

```
if($view->name=='property_list'){ 
// ..got the xml , processed it
// and in the folowing array I added; of course field_address is an item in a content type
$view->result[$i]->field_field_address[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $child->address;
// if i wanted the field to be a link, then altered this array item 
$view->result[$i]->field_field_address[0]['rendered']['#path']['path'] = 'property-detail?id='.$child->ID;  
}
```

The link pointed to another view where the detailed property was shown;

Comment: I did have a test content for this content type and replaced it in the view generation.